# Responsive images with responsive text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I want to add reviews to my site. I'm trying to transpose text over images - its kind of basic. Is there an easy way I can do this using bootstrap? I'v tried using a background image on a `div`, but when the page is resized so is the `div` - image get messed up. I'v tried a few other ways (I found similar questions on the site) the problem is they don't work well with bootstrap because it responsive.

Here's my fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/4ZASB/

I tried using this:

```
image {
position:relative;
```

}

And some other obvious fixes, but no dice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/4ZASB/3/

```
position:absolute;
top:10px;
left:10px;
width:240px; /* from 270px */

font-size:0.8em;
line-height:0.9em;
```